Why do race cars accelerate faster than jets?
In a Top Gear video, the race car has an advantage during the first few seconds of the race. The car accelerates faster, leaving the military jet behind. My question is, why does this happen? Is this due to the fact that propulsive power in an aircraft depends on speed? A quote from a thermodynamics book states:

The power developed from the thrust of the engine is called the propulsive power $W_P$, which is the propulsive force (thrust) times the distance this force acts on the aircraft per unit time, that is, the thrust times the aircraft velocity


$$W_P = F V_\text{aircraft} = m(V_\text{exit} − V_\text{inlet})V_\text{aircraft}$$

Or could it be because a military jet needs significantly more response time to develop thrust from idle to full throttle?

Fighter yet has mass ten times that of car?

@TimRias Yes, but after a while, the jet easily overtakes the car. This means it generates more power per unit of mass, but not during the first seconds of the race

You are know forgetting about drag.

@TimRias No, I don't. The drag on the jet will be higher because it's larger, but it will be less per unit of developed power. If the drag is higher per unit of developed power, then the airplane can't have a maximum speed higher than the car

I feel like this also has something to do with the fact that the car is able to push itself off the ground directly, while the jet has to push air, which offers markedly less resistance to being pushed.

Maybe jet engine gets some benefit from compression of air once it hits a certain velocity?  Not sure, just a hypothesis.

@paulina Jets don't push against air. They eject mass at high velocity backwards, which generates thrust whether there's air behind the engine or not.

@CrisLuengo Yes, but one could view this as the turbine pushing against air which forces it out the back (yes, there is also combustion occurring).  The actual point at which the force pairs are generated is in the turbine which results in the plane being pushed forward and the air (mass) being pushed backwards.

To extend this - a bicycle will accelerate faster than a car, briefly.

When a jet fighter is at the beginning of its take-off roll, its engine accelerates a (relatively) small amount of air to a very high speed. This is not an efficient way to produce thrust at low speed. It can be shown that the propulsive efficiency of a jet engine can be modelled by the following equation:
$$\eta = \frac{2}{1+ \dfrac{v_{\text{exhaust}}}{v_{\text{aircraft}}}}$$
Therefore, when the aircraft velocity is low, the propulsive efficiency is terrible. So, as was stated in the original question, jet engines are not a good way to use power at very low speeds. Furthermore, it is not necessary for the designer to optimise this.
By way of contrast, the racing car has many gears, and so is able to optimise thrust at low speed whilst allowing its engine to spin at a high RPM which is the operating region in which the engine can produce optimal power.
If one does want to optimise thrust at very low speeds (assuming a finite power source), it is necessary to accelerate a huge disk of air by a small amount. One extreme example of this is the AeroVelo Atlas pedal-powered helicopter.
One source in which the above equation is derived is:
Turbojet Engine Theory (MIT lecture notes)

We can also say that in terms of momentum, the car uses the entire Earth as a working fluid. The mass of Earth is much bigger than mass of air so it ends up in pure acceleration a=F/m where F can be as high as a friction force on wheels and m is the mass of the car.

Beyond efficiency issues, I would expect that jet engines use a plane's airspeed to assist with air intake.  Reducing air intake speed while maintaining a constant fuel/air mixture would reduce power even if efficiency stayed constant.

The callout to car gears is a good one here. If a car started in a higher gear, you'd see the exact same acceleration pattern as the jet, i.e. initially struggling but eventually picking up the pace considerably.

Acceleration is proportional to force/mass. The main difference is that car can multiply the accelerating force using low gears and has a lower mass in the first place.

Since the aircraft in this case is well below stall speed (since it's not e.g. a helicopter) wouldn't one optimize thrust by putting drive power to the wheels (like the car is doing) or another method like a catapault?

The drive train to add power to the wheels would be a huge amount of weight and complexity just to shorten the take-off slightly. It is better just to build a long enough runway. This weight would then need to be carried throughout the whole flight. Aircraft undercarriages are quite lightly built and compact compared to the drive trains of ground vehicles. Catapults are already used on aircraft carriers.

When saying "It can be shown", it is always nice to give a citation or link to a source where it actually is shown.

A jet engine (like almost every other IC engine) relies on atmospheric air for the combustion process - I would suspect that at a stand-still, the amount of air entering the engine would force the engine to run very rich (or limit the fuel used) compared to running at high speed. I believe it is standard practice for a jet landing on an aircraft carrier to actually select full power a moment BEFORE landing, just so that the engines have actually spooled back up to full speed if a go-around is needed, since there is a noticable lag.

I have now added a source which hopefully is useful.

Frame challenge: Why should the jet accelerate faster? This just seems to be an assumption from you.
Acceleration is given by force divided by mass. It's that simple. Whichever vehicle has the larger force/mass ratio will accelerate more.
If you think about the car, it is no surprise it excels at this. Acceleration through its operating range (say 0-100mph) is a key design goal and as such it will be designed with a low mass and a power system optimised for traction. Past a certain velocity the jet's vastly superior power (and hence its ability to exert a high force at that velocity) enables it claw back and overtake the car. The jet is designed as an air-superiority fighter and its standing start acceleration isn't key to that.

At the beginning of this answer it is stated: "Why should the jet accelerate faster? This just seems to be an assumption from you." Well, it is not 'just an assumption" - the original question clearly states that it was shown in a Top Gear video. There is nothing wrong with asking why the initial acceleration of the jet lags and doesn't match the later acceleration. And yes, in another answer the fact that a jet designer does not need to optimise acceleration from a standing start has been mentioned - if a short take-off an aircraft carrier is required there are catapults for that.

OP has not made any assumptions here: for example, they have not suggested that they think that the Jet should accelerate faster.  They have merely stated an situation, citing empirical evidence/example, and asked why or how the result observed occurred.

Add to that that the car can transfer its power on a solid surface while the jet engine can only move air.

The fastest accelerating cars in the world are jet powered drag cars.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If the jet engine could move enough air (e.g. the same mass of air as the earth) then why would "only moving air" be an issue? I think the real issue is that the jet is accelerating a small amount of air to a high speed rather than slightly accelerating a huge mass of air.
